# map method in many_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following 3 models in my application:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :linkedsubmissions
end

class Linkedsubmission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission
  has_many   :lnksubtypes
end


class Lnksubtype < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :linkedsubmission
end
```

In the code below '`@submission.linkedsubmissions.lnksubtypes`' is incorrect.

```
@history = Audit.find(:all, :conditions => ["auditable_id IN (?)",@submission.linkedsubmissions.lnksubtypes.map{|b| b.LSU_ID} ])
```

I need to find all audits with 'auditable_id' in @submission.linkedsubmissions.lnksubtypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following `has_many` relationship to your `Submission` model.

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :linkedsubmissions
 has_many :lnksubtypes, :through => :linkedsubmissions
end
```

Now, you'll be able to reformat your query like this

```
@history = Audit.find(:all, :conditions => ["auditable_id IN (?)", @submission.lnksubtypes.map(&:LSU_ID) ])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Audit.find(:all, :conditions => ["auditable_id IN (?)",@submission.linkedsubmissions.map{|b| b.lnksubtypes.map{&:LSU_OID) }.flatten ])
```

But there should be a better way to get those LSU_OID with sql only.

Answer (score 1):

```
@history = Audit.where(:auditable_id => @submission.lnksubtypes.map(&:LSU_ID))
```

slightly shorter

Comment: I wanted to write that but I wasn't really sure about the ROR version here :)